# Setting up freeswitch server on Google cloud compute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, freeswitch, telecommunication

I am trying setup freeswitch server on google cloud compute (ubuntu 14.04) although it work fine for me locally, I seem to get the following error when I start freeswitch server on google cloud compute.Can any one explain?

```
2015-06-11 05:40:32.001508 [ERR] sofia.c:2853 Error Creating SIP UA for profile: internal-ipv6 (sip:mod_sofia@[::1]
:5060;transport=udp,tcp) ATTEMPT 2 (RETRY IN 5 SEC)
2015-06-11 05:40:32.001508 [ERR] sofia.c:2853 Error Creating SIP UA for profile: external-ipv6 (sip:mod_sofia@[::1]
:5080;transport=udp,tcp) ATTEMPT 2 (RETRY IN 5 SEC)
2015-06-11 05:40:37.001491 [ERR] sofia.c:2853 Error Creating SIP UA for profile: internal-ipv6 (sip:mod_sofia@[::1]
:5060;transport=udp,tcp) ATTEMPT 3 (RETRY IN 5 SEC)
2015-06-11 05:40:37.001491 [ERR] sofia.c:2863 Error Creating SIP UA for profile: internal-ipv6 (sip:mod_sofia@[::1]
:5060;transport=udp,tcp)
The likely causes for this are:
1) Another application is already listening on the specified address.
2) The IP the profile is attempting to bind to is not local to this system.
2015-06-11 05:40:37.001491 [ERR] sofia.c:2853 Error Creating SIP UA for profile: external-ipv6 (sip:mod_sofia@[::1]
:5080;transport=udp,tcp) ATTEMPT 3 (RETRY IN 5 SEC)
2015-06-11 05:40:37.001491 [ERR] sofia.c:2863 Error Creating SIP UA for profile: external-ipv6 (sip:mod_sofia@[::1]
:5080;transport=udp,tcp)
The likely causes for this are:
1) Another application is already listening on the specified address.
2) The IP the profile is attempting to bind to is not local to this system.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found answer for this myself at
http://lists.freeswitch.org/mailman/listinfo/freeswitch-users

So this issue is related to ipv6. Since google didn't provide ipv6, I had to disable ipv6 in freeswitch

In conf/sip_profiles directory you will find files regarding ipv6,

```
    abcd@instance-1:/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/sip_profiles$ ls
    external  external-ipv6  external-ipv6.xml  external.xml  internal-ipv6.xml  internal.xml
```

In order to disable ipv6 in freeswitch we need to rename to something like external-ipv6.xml.inactive or we can move/remove these files.

But make sure you only rename/remove files/folders regarding ipv6, So here I removed files `external-ipv6` , `internal-ipv6.xml`, `external-ipv6.xml`

And then restart Freeswitch server

**EDIT:**

BEFORE:

```
# ls
external  external-ipv6  external-ipv6.xml.inactive  external.xml  internal-ipv6.xml  internal.xml
```

AFTER:

```
# ls
external  external-ipv6.inactive  external-ipv6.xml.inactive  external.xml  internal-ipv6.xml.inactive  internal.xml
```